# How to control what classes can extend my class in Java

Tags: java, oop, sealed-class

So I was asked this question in interview that if I have a class A how do I restrict which classes will be able to extend A. For example if I want only class C and E to be able to extend A and classes B and D should not be able to do so. I mentioned about bounded wildcards in generics but I think that didn't answer the question. I am not aware about any new feature added in newer versions of Java. Please let me know what is the correct answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sealed classes](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sealed-classes-interfaces) seems to be one method to restrict which classes can extend another. This feature is available since Java 17.

Contraints:

- All permitted subclasses must belong to the same module as the sealed class.
- Every permitted subclass must explicitly extend the sealed class.
- Every permitted subclass must define a modifier: final, sealed, or non-sealed.

Example:

```java
public abstract sealed class Vehicle permits Car, Truck {...}
```

This restricts that only classes Car or Truck can extend Vehicle.

Comment: Thanks, would you recommend a book I could read to update myself on all the new features in recent versions. I am stuck at Java 8.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not aware of any. Also note that [recommendations are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Shivam..., I recommend any Java book by _O'Reilly Media_, they cover a wide range of Java topics; _"core Java"_ is the term you're looking for, and will typically cover class inheritance well.  Additionally, any book by _Oracle_, the company which currently owns _Java_, is typically a good choice.  Additionally, if you're looking for this specific mechanism, a _"sealed class"_, you'll want a book specific to Java 17 or after.

Comment: Check out [Java Magazine](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/) which is an `Oracle` publication.  Another possibility is [JavaWorld](https://www.infoworld.com/category/java/) which is a subcategory of `InforWorld.com.`